# How to define arrays of objects in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

When defining an array of objects in a Mongoose schema as so:

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    stuff : [ Object ]
});
```

When trying to save an instance of this object, with 'stuff' filled up with some objects, Mongoose gives the following error: "Object # has no method 'cast'"

What is the correct way to declare an array of objects in Mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ObjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //your object schema
});

var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    stuff : [ ObjectSchema ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the sub-object is coming from an external source and I have no control over its layout. Its quite large, and I don't want to design a schema for it myself. I just want to have a single schema, for my data, with an array of these external objects in it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
stuff1 :{type:String},
stuff2 :{type:Number},
array :[{arraystuff1:{type:String}}]
});
```

Here is a link where you can find information about it
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: I can't accept my own answer till tomorrow, but I have figured it out and see below for a better solution. Basically, you don't need any of that "arraystuff1" stuff. Just having " array: [] " is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it further, the way to do is is to **not** use the Object type provided by Mongoose, as that causes problems. Instead just define it as an array:

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    stuff : [ ]
});
```

This works, lets you put whatever you want into it and will save it correctly.